# How to reset global variables before each test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Let's say I have a function that returns an id (integer) that increments every time.

```
let nextId = 0;

const getId = () => nextId++;

export default  getId;
```

I will have multiple tests for this function. Normally, in each test, I expect the id to be reset, meaning that the first time i call the function in each test, the returned value should be 0, but that's not the case. The value is persisted cross tests.

```
import getId  from './getId'

describe('getId()', () => {
  it('test1', () => {
    expect(getId()).toEqual(0); //passes
    expect(getId()).toEqual(1); //passes
  })
  it('test2', () => {
    expect(getId()).toEqual(0); //fails
  })
})
```

How to address this problem? Is having a global variable `nextId` a bad idea?

Comment: You can use `beforeEach` function according to [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown)

Comment: Adding to what @luckongas said, you probably want to call [`jest.resetModules()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetmodules) in `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should do the job.

```js
let nextId = 0;

const getId = () => nextId++;

export default getId;
```

```js
import getId from './getId'

describe('getId()', () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules());
  it('test1', () => {
    expect(getId()).toEqual(0); //passes
    expect(getId()).toEqual(1); //passes
  })
  it('test2', () => {
    expect(getId()).toEqual(0); //fails
  })
})
```

Any issue, please, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Yes, having a global variable for this is a bad idea. Global variables are more difficult to control because anything can alter them. I would just use a simple class.

```js
class IdManager() {
    constructor() {
        this.last_id = 0;
    }

    getId() {
        this.last_id++;
        return this.last_id;
    }

}
```

Then create a new Id manager every time you start a new test.

```js
let id_man = new IdManager();
let id = id_man.getId();
```